# python Cannot write file when import module function

Tags: python

I created a module "test" with these code:

```
def write_file():
    with open("testw.txt", 'w') as t:
        t.writelines("test ok")
        print(t)
```

if import from other module and run below code:

```
import test

test.write_file()
```

it can print out: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='testw.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp950'>
but the file cannot create!

If i run write_file() in test module, it can create the file just fine, how can i write the file while the write file code is import from other module?

Comment: You probably imported it with another directory current and `testw.txt` ended up there.

Comment: @Davis 
you are right, just checked it is not the same directory, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Um there are 2 ways you could do it i guess.

First:

Create a different folder called test_module and add the test.py file into the directory. Also ad a blank **init**.py file to the folder.

so if you do this,

```
import test_module
test_module.test.write_file()


or...

from test_module import test
test.write_file()
```

It should probably work

The second way is this

```
import .test as test
test.write_file()
```

you could also do this

```
from .test import write_file
write_file()
```